# Jacobian for transformation of discrete random variables (intuition)

Tags: probability, random-variable, intuition, jacobian

I am reading Blitzstein's introduction to probability. He states that, while a transformation of continuous r.v.s needs a Jacobian (or derivative), a transformation of discrete r.v.s does not.

Is there a way to *intuitively* explain why this is the case? What concepts are needed to understand why this is so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an attempt at an intuitive explanation for the transformation $f(x) = 2x$.

Discrete case: a discrete random variable is like a collection of point masses. Imagine a collection of rocks of different masses on the real line. Applying $f$ moves each rock twice as far away from the origin, but the mass of each rock hasn't changed and the number of rocks hasn't changed.

Continuous case: imagine a rubber band of constant density lying along the real line, where the cross-sectional area (CSA) of the band at $x$ corresponds to the probability density function at $x$. If you apply $f$ without the Jacobian, that would be like stretching the rubber band by a factor of 2 and expecting its CSA not to change. In order for the total mass of the rubber band to be preserved (which corresponds to preserving the total probability of 1), we have to multiply its CSA by 0.5. This is the Jacobian factor.